# Array that takes user input to fill but does not allow duplicate elements

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a part of a program that I have for an assignment. This part of the program should take 8 user inputed integers to fill however if the user inputs a digit that has already been inputed an error is displayed and the user is asked to input a different number. As of yet I haven't written the error code and second attempt part of the code because I am having issues with the checking for duplicates part. At present the out put is True no matter what I put in.

```
int maxNum = 8;
int[] arrayIn = new int[maxNum];
boolean duplicates = false;

// Run while not true
while (!duplicates) {
    // For loop for input into array
    for (int j = 0; j < maxNum; j++) {
        System.out.println("Enter digit " + digCounter + ":");
        arrayIn[j] = in1.nextInt();
        digCounter++;
        // Check for duplicates
        for (int a = 0; a < maxNum; a++) {
            for (int k = a + 1; k < maxNum; k++) {
                if (k != a && arrayIn[k] == arrayIn[a]) {
                    // Quit loop if duplicate found
                    duplicates = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(duplicates);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into a collection called `Set`. There is a pretty handy function `Set.contains` that will return `true` or `false` depending if a number is already in the `Set` or not.  Something like this would do the trick:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int maxNum = 8;
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
int digCounter = 1;

//Run while we need numbers
while (digCounter <= maxNum) {
    System.out.println("Enter digit " + digCounter + ":");
    int tempNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    if (numbers.contains(tempNumber)) { //If number is already chosen
        System.out.println("Sorry that number has already been added");
    } else { //If new number
        digCounter++;
        numbers.add(tempNumber);
    }
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Or if you HAVE to use only arrays you can do something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int maxNum = 8;
int[] arrayIn = new int[maxNum];
boolean duplicate;
int digCounter = 1;

// Run while we need numbers
while (digCounter <= maxNum) {
    //reset duplicate
    duplicate = false;
    //Get user input
    System.out.println("Enter digit " + digCounter + ":");
    int temp = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= digCounter - 2; i++) { //Loop through accepted numbers
        if (temp == arrayIn[i]) { //We have found a match
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Check if duplicate
    if (duplicate) {
        System.out.println("Sorry that number has already been added");
    } else {
        arrayIn[digCounter - 1] = temp;
        digCounter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayIn));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sets will work fine but it looks like he HAS to use arrays... (like for an homework)

Comment: @ParkerHalo I have updated the solution to use arrays.

Comment: ah nice one! Just wanted to point out that he might need that! gj!

Answer (score 0):

This code will also work if you don't want to use set.

```
    // creating the array
    int[] array = new int[10];

    // Taking the first number
    System.out.println("Please enter your numbers: ");
    array[0] = input.nextInt();

    // taking other inputs
    int count;
    for (count = 1; count < array.length; count++) {
        int num = input.nextInt();

        // Scanning the array for the number
        int n;
        for (n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            while (array[n] == num) { // This will also work if the user
                                        // wants to give duplicate after
                                        // duplicate
                System.out.println("You have entered this number before! Add another..");
                num = input.nextInt();
                n = 0;
            }

        }
        array[count] = num;

    }
```